# Are Intent objects always necessary to perform any action in Android development?

Tags: android-intent

I've recently started learning the basics of developing for Android phones, and so far it's pretty straight forward. I learned about intents and what their purpose is, and it makes sense that the functionality for emitting and intercepting 'global' events exists.

However, now that I've finished some tutorials, the first thing I feel I need to do is learn how to avoid intents 99% of the time. I understand their purpose, but I see no need to create new objects/threads/processes for a scenario where a button click sets a text field value.

I'd be surprised if I was the first one looking for the convenience of 'textbox2.text = textbox1.text' so I'm assuming that I simply haven't learned about the feature I'm looking for. Or perhaps workarounds have been produced that hide all the boilerplate? Or perhaps by simply not using intents and accessing UI elements directly, it's completely fine but I miss out on facilitating listeners that I didn't want listening anyway?

Comment: The short answer is "no". You seem to be very confused. Please post an example of what you are talking about. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Hey David, not sure why you need to tell me that I'm confused when you're the one struggling to understand :) If you review the example at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html you'll see that they use Intent objects to accomplish setting the text in a field after a button is clicked. This is very different from any other environment I've programmed in where I'm trying to set the value of a text field after a button is clicked. I do not wish to broadcast a message, nor do I want my logic to be outside the sendMessage method.

Comment: I'm not struggling to understand Android, I'm struggling to answer your vague question. I have no idea why you think you need to _avoid intents 99% of the time_., nor do I understand what _facilitating listeners that I didn't want listening anyway_ means. It would still be useful if you would give an example of what you mean. In any case, I've provided an answer which I hope will help to "unconfuse" you about the use of `Intent`s.

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial you referenced in your comment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) is used to illustrate basic concepts. In this case it shows how to start one Activity from another and pass data to it. Don't use that tutorial as a best-practice guide for how to write Android apps.

Of course you don't need to use an `Intent` to copy data from one field to another, or from one variable to another (within a single Activity. However, the standard way to pass data from one Activity to another is via `Intent` extras. There are a number of reasons for this. The most important reason is that Android can kill the process hosting your app at any time, and the user will expect that, when he returns to your app he ends up in the same place he was when he left it. To support this functionality, each Activity needs to save and restore its state (using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` and any data passed between activities needs to be put in an `Intent` (which Android stores in its own data structures).